# Extend space for Ubuntu 18.10 by adding unallocated space to partition

Tags: partitioning, 18.10

I have Ubuntu 18.10 installed and I am running out of space. I have unallocated space of 7 GB which I want to add to Ubuntu. Please guide me on how to achieve it.

Comment: Extending the partition depends on the fact where the unallocated space is. Do post a screenshot of GParted. If they are contiguous congrats you can extend otherwise you can't.

Answer (score 1):

I find GParted to be the easiest tool to do this here is a link to explanation on how it works. I do recommend taking back up before doing any partitioning.

https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

Ok so first you want to download GParted and make a USB bootable disk. Easiest tool for that to use is Rufus.

Once you have it boot from it. (This is because you cant have your disks mounted while trying to partition them).

You will get a GUI and most probably the icon for GParted will be in the top left corner. Once you open that up you will get a screen such as this.
[image]

Next select the partition you want to extend. You have to make sure the space you have free is to the right of the partition. If you have more than one you have to shuffle other partitions further to the right until you get a free space there. Also if you do need to resize another partition (Part B) to the right of the partition you are looking at originally (Part A) remember to save changes in between as otherwise it will not allow you to extend you Partition A as Partition B is still in the way until you commit changes.
This is the kind of screen you will get while resizing.
[image]

Comment: This is really a link-only answer and if the link is dead the answer becomes invalid. Please add the relevant part in the answer itself.

Comment: Please update the answer as per that shared link!